# The Primitive type int of y does not have a field during Compiling

Tags: java

I am writing a program to perform some arithmetic operations on integers gotten from user. I keep getting an error concerning the subtract variable not being a primitive type int.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

//This program is used to display the sum, product, difference and quotient of two numbers

public class test6 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //Create a scanner to obtain user input
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int x,y; //Declare the two integer variables
        int sum, product;
        double quotient;
        long subtract;

        System.out.println("Enter the first integer: "); //Prompt user for input
        x = input.nextInt(); //Read first integer

        System.out.println("Enter the second integer: "); //Prompt user for input
        y = input.nextInt(); //Read second integer

        sum = x + y; //Calculate the sum of the two integers
        subtract = x - y; //Calculate the subtract of the two integer
        product = x * y; //Calculate the product of the two integers
        quotient = x % y; //Calculate the quotient of the two integers

        System.out.printf("The sum of %d and %d is %d", x , y, sum);

        System.out.printf("The difference of %d and %d is %d", x , y. subtract);

        System.out.printf("The product of %d and %d is %d", x , y, product);

        System.out.printf("The quotient of %d and %d is %d", x , y , quotient);

    }

}
```

Comment: Edit: you have written `y. subtract)`, but it needs to be a comma..
The compiler thinks that you are now trying to acces the field `subtract` from the primitive `y`, which doesn´t exist.

Comment: Kevin is right, subtract is declared as long, this means "long floating point".
You must declare it as int or bigint.

Comment: @KevinEsche Hi kevin, even when declared as an int which i just did.. The error still persists

Comment: @SergioInternicola No, it means `long integer, 64-bits`.

Comment: @Kayaman You're right (this happens when you program in too many languages... :-) )
The solution is to convert int to long: subtract = (long) x - (long) y;

Comment: @SergioInternicola No that's not the solution at all.

Comment: @SergioInternicola there is no point in hard converting to type long... The double type is sufficient enough for the program

Comment: @Kayaman The program works fine now... I just changed the variable subtract to type integer and the variable quotient to double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have a `typo` in line

```
 System.out.printf("The difference of %d and %d is %d", x , y. subtract);
```

Change your `dot` to `comma`.
As @Kevin pointed the compiler tries to resolve `subtract` as a field on the `int` variable.

```
System.out.printf("The difference of %d and %d is %d", x , y, subtract);
```

Comment: Thanks! I honestly didnt see that... The program runs just fine now... I really appreciate

Comment: The variable quotient should also be defined as a type long

Answer (score 0):

The variable quotient is not an integer type. As it is the the result of the remainder of an integer division. It should be defined as a type double